# A TikZ code needed for the diagram generated by the following PSTrick code

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like a TiKZ code to generate the following diagram, drawn with the following  PSTrick code, to draw two concentric flower petals diagram, arranged in a circle,
one with 8 petals and the outer with 16 petals.
(This is part of a Sri yantra (or Sri chakra) drawing found in various sites, for example:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42410/draw-sri-yantra

Here is the PSTrick Code

```
\SpecialCoor
\qdisk(0,0){5pt}
\multido{\rAngleA=-11.25+22.50,\rAngleB=11.25+22.50}{16}{%
  \pscustom[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid]{%
    \psarc(0,0){6.5}{\rAngleA}{\rAngleB}
    \psbezier%
      (! 6.5 \rAngleB\space cos mul 6.5 \rAngleB\space sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleB\space 7.75 sub def 8 a cos mul 8 a sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleB\space 10.25 sub def 7 a cos mul 7 a sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleB\space 11.25 sub def 8 a cos mul 8 a sin mul)
    \psbezier%
      (! /a \rAngleA\space 11.25 add def 8 a cos mul 8 a sin mul)
      (! /a \rAngleA\space 10.25 add def 7 a cos mul 7 a sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleA\space 7.75 add def 8 a cos mul 8 a sin mul)%
      (! 6.5 \rAngleA\space cos mul 6.5 \rAngleA\space sin mul)%
  }
}

\multido{\rAngleA=-22.5+45.0,\rAngleB=22.5+45.0}{8}{%
  \pscustom[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid]{%
    \psarc(0,0){5.5}{\rAngleA}{\rAngleB}
    \psbezier%
      (! 5.5 \rAngleB\space cos mul 5.5 \rAngleB\space sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleB\space 6.75 sub def 7 a cos mul 7 a sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleB\space 12.5 sub def 5 a cos mul 5 a sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleB\space 22.5 sub def 6.5 a cos mul 6.5 a sin mul)
    \psbezier%
      (! /a \rAngleA\space 22.5 add def 6.5 a cos mul 6.5 a sin mul)
      (! /a \rAngleA\space 12.5 add def 5 a cos mul 5 a sin mul)%
      (! /a \rAngleA\space 6.75 add def 7 a cos mul 7 a sin mul)%
      (! 5.5 \rAngleA\space cos mul 5.5 \rAngleA\space sin mul)%
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the need to convert this to Ti*k*Z? Why don't you just create a PDF from it and place it in your document via `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Did you try to find it here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271991/1952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick conversion of the above code would probably result in something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=5pt];
\foreach \i in {0,...,16} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rAngleA}{-11.25+(22.50*\i)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rAngleB}{11.25+(22.50*\i)}
    \path[draw, fill=blue] 
        (\rAngleA:6.5) arc[radius=6.5, start angle=\rAngleA, end angle=\rAngleB] --
        ({6.5*cos(\rAngleB)},{6.5*sin(\rAngleB)}) .. controls 
        ({8*cos(\rAngleB-7.75)},{8*sin(\rAngleB-7.75)}) and 
        ({7*cos(\rAngleB-10.25)},{7*sin(\rAngleB-10.25)}) ..
        ({8*cos(\rAngleB-11.25)},{8*sin(\rAngleB-11.25)}) --
        ({8*cos(\rAngleA+11.25)},{8*sin(\rAngleA+11.25)}) .. controls 
        ({7*cos(\rAngleA+10.25)},{7*sin(\rAngleA+10.25)}) and 
        ({8*cos(\rAngleA+7.75)},{8*sin(\rAngleA+7.75)}) ..
        ({6.5*cos(\rAngleA)},{6.5*sin(\rAngleA)}) -- cycle;
    \path[draw] 
        (0,0) -- ({6.5*cos(\rAngleA)},{6.5*sin(\rAngleA)})
        (0,0) -- ({8*cos(\rAngleB-11.25)},{8*sin(\rAngleB-11.25)});
}
\foreach \i in {0,...,8} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rAngleA}{-22.5+(45.0*\i)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rAngleB}{22.5+(45.0*\i)}
    \path[draw, fill=red] 
        (\rAngleA:5.5) arc[radius=5.5, start angle=\rAngleA, end angle=\rAngleB] --
        ({5.5*cos(\rAngleB)},{5.5*sin(\rAngleB)}) .. controls
        ({7*cos(\rAngleB-6.75)},{7*sin(\rAngleB-6.75)}) and
        ({5*cos(\rAngleB-12.5)},{5*sin(\rAngleB-12.5)}) ..
        ({6.5*cos(\rAngleB-22.5)},{6.5*sin(\rAngleB-22.5)}) --
        ({6.5*cos(\rAngleA+22.5)},{6.5*sin(\rAngleA+22.5)}) .. controls
        ({5*cos(\rAngleA+12.5)},{5*sin(\rAngleA+12.5)}) and
        ({7*cos(\rAngleA+6.75)},{7*sin(\rAngleA+6.75)}) ..
        ({5.5*cos(\rAngleA)},{5.5*sin(\rAngleA)}) -- cycle;
    \path[draw] 
        (0,0) -- ({5.5*cos(\rAngleA)},{5.5*sin(\rAngleA)})
        (0,0) -- ({6.5*cos(\rAngleB-22.5)},{6.5*sin(\rAngleB-22.5)});
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]